# How to change a column date type to ISO8601?

Tags: postgresql, date, migration, ruby-on-rails-6, sqldatatypes

Using Rails 6.1 and PostgreSQL 13, how do we change the default date format of an existing column to ISO8601 ?

Could we generate a migration like:

```rb
class ChangeDateFormatToISO8601 < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    execute('ALTER COLUMN "table"."column" SET DATA TYPE ISO8601;')
  end

  # OR

  def change
    change_column :table, :column, :datetime, datetime_type: :iso_8601
  end
end
```

Comment: A `DATE` column has no (implied) format. Any formatting you see of (true) `DATE` values are applied by the application _displaying_ those values. As a result of that you can't change the "formatting" of a column. You can only change the format the application uses to display date values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand it right, it must be done at the application level, and changing the format (ie. using `strftime`) has no cost ? Thus I should define default datetype inside a initializer or cast `.iso8601`. I naively thought having the wished format stored inside the DB would have slightly improve performances

Comment: A `date` value is stored **without** any format in a binary representation. Formatting this would make this slower, because this means it must be converted into a formatted string which also takes more space - way less efficient (and versatile)

Comment: And ISO  8601 is not a format. It is a large collection of time and date formats (and period, and intervals), as basis to select a real format. We see a lot of the date, date-time formats (but mostly without the optional `T` letter). It is not uncommon to have week format. And do not forget the variations with or without time offset informations

Comment: Thank you both for these claifications